# how to apply the style for clone sheet in phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using php excel code in that how to give some particular style like bold row height and merge column as same like activesheet.

I'm using the clone active sheet for `getActiveSheet` the style are applying for the cloning sheet kpioverview the styles are not applying where i'm doing mistake ?

```
$clonedSheet = clone $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$salesperson = clone $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$kpioverview = clone $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

//GetMOnth
$previous_month = date('F', strtotime('-1 month'));

//Set Background
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:K1')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF808080');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, 1, "MOnth".$previous_month);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('A1:K1');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:K1')->getFont()->setBold(true)->setSize(16);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:K1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);


//KPI Overview
$kpioverview->getStyle('B1:N1')->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FF808080');
$kpioverview->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 1, "Shipment KPI Overview Testing");
$kpioverview->mergeCells('B1:N1');
$kpioverview->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
$kpioverview->getStyle('B1:N1')->getFont()->setBold(true)->setSize(14);
$kpioverview->getStyle('B1:N1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're cloning sheets, but not doing anything with them, and you're cloning them before setting styles so they'll be a clone without those styles.

Set the styles and then clone them, or make each one active in turn and apply the styles to each in turn

Comment: how to make each one active for clone sheets ?

Comment: To make a sheet active you use the methods like `setActiveSheetIndex()` or `setActiveSheetIndexByName()`.... or you can use `getSheet()` or `getSheetByName()` instead of `getActiveSheet()`

Comment: i have clone 4 sheets i need to be active 4th sheet how should i give   `setActiveSheetIndex(3)` ? is it right ?

Comment: `setActiveSheetIndex(3)` will make the 4th sheet active, because offset starts at 0, just like PHP array offsets

Comment: can u please provide the example for the above question ?